# Documentation for linux qsub and PBS options - where to find it?

Tags: pbs

i'm trying to distribute multiple jobs over limited number of "long" queues available, as otherwise i get an error `qsub: submit error (Maximum number of jobs already in queue for user MSG=total number of current user's jobs exceeds the queue limit: user rai**, queue long)`

May i ask if there is a manual that would give me deeper understanding over the following part of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -q long
#PBS -l ddisk=30000 -l feature=largescratch
```

...and would allow to distribute jobs better.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting appears to be linked to user limits rather than generic `qsub` parameters or PBS options. Unfortunately, to my knowledge there is no standard on how user limits are created. You'll need to look for documentation for the specific HPC you're using. The ones that I've used provide good documentation, but had quite different limits for any given user.

For example, here are the ones for [QMUL](https://docs.hpc.qmul.ac.uk/using/) and [Imperial college](https://www.imperial.ac.uk/admin-services/ict/self-service/research-support/rcs/support/getting-started/).